# Not showing Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library

Tags: android

I have updated all latest versions in my SDK manager but yet not showing Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library in SDK (in Extra).

Please help me. Is there any other option there in place Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library? I will be thankful for that.

Answer (score 7):

Just tick the "Obsolete" checkbox in Android SDK Manager popup.

Answer (score 0):

GCM is integrated in Google play services

Comment: if GCM is integrated in Google play service so how can i implement pushnotification application and implement google play service with my project plz help asap

Comment: you have to use google play services as an external library. Its all there in the docs.

Comment: I've down-voted this answer as it does not reference the source of your information.

As per http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html you are correct in saying it is intergrated:

"This document tells you how to get started setting up a GCM implementation. Before you begin, make sure to set up the Google Play Services SDK. You need this SDK to use the GoogleCloudMessaging methods."


But I would suggest adding a little more detail for the asker; perhaps with a link to relevant ref. docs (ie: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

Comment: @cgr you are right buddy. please if anyone have doubt than please refer this link - http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html and see that gcm is included in play services.